# Is it ok to poll Azure SQL Database "very" often?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Since we cannot use Service Broker on Azure SQL Database, is it ok to poll every 250ms?

The query should be fairly light as it is executed against a table that has very few records. Whenever a new record is found, it is processed and deleted.

Will I get charged extra?

Comment: Consider that 250ms is a relatively short time, and network roundtrip times may be above this for certain situations. Also consider what happens when your data grows. DB servers can easily handle such frequency, but take resource usage into account.

Comment: It's often better to let client applications to notify when something happens than polling, if you can change them.

Comment: Try and make something event-driven eg Event Grid or Data Factory blob trigger or custom trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Azure SQL Database you get charged by hours consumed of reserved resources, it does not matter if you use the resources or not, you have them reserved and you pay hourly for those resources assigned to your subscription. The only exception is Azure Serverless where you are charged by the minute, and the database is auto-paused after 1 hour or more of inactivity (depending of how you configured it).

You won't be charged by bandwidth in egress also as you are deleting rows.

In summary, that kind of activity on the database won't make you pay more.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be fine and you won't be charged per transaction if you are on DTU's or vCores plan.